# Alert is showing but data is not updating and not able to click ok button of alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My Alert is showing that updated successfully but data is not updating in database and not able to click ok button of alert. Here is my php code for upresult.php. Hope This will b helpful. Thank you in advance

my jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
              $.ajax({

                 url:"upresult.php",
                 type:"POST",
                 data:formData,
                 async:true,
                 success:function(data) {
                   alert(data);

                },
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false
            });
         });
    });
```

upresult.php

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    $no=trim($_POST['upno']);
    $name=trim($_POST['upname']);
    $mob=trim($_POST['upmob_no']);
    $dob=trim($_POST['updob']);
    $add=trim($_POST['upadd']);
    $photo=trim($_FILES['upphoto']['name']);
    $gen=trim($_POST['gender']);
    $cn=trim($_POST['upcountry']);
    $st=trim($_POST['upstate']);
    $ct=trim($_POST['upcity']);

    $qry="update stud set stud_name='".$name."',mobile='".$mob."',dob='".$dob."',address='".$add."',gender='".$gen."',country='".$cn."',state='".$st."',city='".$ct."' where stud_no='".$no."'";
    $data=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
    if($data)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Updated Successfully")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Cannot update record")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: These symptoms imply that your AJAX request is working fine, so the problem will be in your PHP logic. To help you, we need to see that code instead. That being said, it's very odd to send a FormData object in an object. Try changing to `data: formData`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have added php code

Comment: @JaicyJoseph is your update query working?

Comment: You cannot return JS and expect it to execute like that. I'd suggest first checking if your query is working, and then amend your PHP to return JSON instead

Comment: Pretty sure all those $_POST entries you are trying to access don’t actually exist. (And if you had proper PHP error reporting enabled, it would have already told you that - so go do that now please!) By using `data:{formData:formData}` you made jQuery send the whole thing as a parameter named `formData`, so all those fields should be under `$_POST['formData']` now.

Comment: @misorude oh ok, but i changed that and made it data: formData, but still its not working

Comment: Do you have proper error reporting enabled? Do you get an errors in the output of your script? (Check that in the network panel of our browser dev tools.)

Comment: @misorude in this nothing showing, i am using console to see if any error is coming or not.

Comment: may be your update query not working..

Comment: @Kiranramchandran ya i think, when i did echo of that query not showing any values

Comment: _“i am using console to see if any error is coming or not”_ - the browser console show JS errors and network errors, but it won’t show you errors that happened inside your PHP script. Go check the actual response of that script, in the network panel. (And do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, or not?)

Answer (score 1):

You want to alert alert. Try with editing your flow control structure like this:

```
<?php

    include("connection.php");

    // you need to validate this data before sending it to update query 
    $no=trim($_POST['upno']);
    $name=trim($_POST['upname']);
    $mob=trim($_POST['upmob_no']);
    $dob=trim($_POST['updob']);
    $add=trim($_POST['upadd']);
    $photo=trim($_FILES['upphoto']['name']);
    $gen=trim($_POST['gender']);
    $cn=trim($_POST['upcountry']);
    $st=trim($_POST['upstate']);
    $ct=trim($_POST['upcity']);

    // this parameters should be binded to avoid SQL injection
    $query = "
        update stud 
        set
            stud_name = '$name',
            mobile = '$mob', 
            dob = '$dob', 
            address = '$add',
            gender = '$gen',
            country = '$cn',
            state = '$st',
            city = '$ct'
        where stud_no = '$no';
    ";

    /** This may be query for checking.
    *   Just execute it after first query and grab response from it.
    *   Depends of response you will return appropirate text message.
    */
    $checkUpdateQuery = "
        select if(count(*) = 1, true, false) as response
        from stud
        where stud_name = '$name',
        and mobile = '$mob', 
        and dob = '$dob', 
        and address = '$add',
        and gender = '$gen',
        and country = '$cn',
        and state = '$st',
        and city = '$ct'
        and stud_no = '$no'; 
    ";

    /** mysqli_query will return false only if some error occurred. 
    *   In other cases you will get true, 
    *   so you need to check if data is updated by another query.
    */
    $data = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    echo $data ? 'Updated Successfully' : 'Cannot update record';
```

Few things you should consider is do you have certain stud_no in database, mysqli_query returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

If you want we can change this query. Can you use PDO instead of mysqli?

Comment: Its showing update successfully but actually not updating

Comment: Ok, we have fixed part with alert. Let me change php code for this case.

Comment: I did echo for my update but it didnt showed any value its showing this - > update stud set stud_name='',mobile='',dob='',address='',gender='',country='',state='',city='' where stud_no='' Updated Successfully @AkeksandarRakic

Comment: See comment above in answer.

Comment: My stud_no button is disabled, is it because of that not able to update?

Comment: I dont know PDO @AleksandarRakic

Comment: Ok, we will set it up with this one, give me 10 minutes for this.

Comment: I gave you example in answer above, try to implement it on that way. And try to read and work with PDO to avoid this kind of things.

Comment: Problem is with alert button, i think, update is showing values

Comment: When you click on some button, it will run some ajax call. That call will call php script which part of code you shared with use on this page. After update, when you check records in database, update seams to work. Am I right?